# I left them (at) home

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

Consider this question:

> Where are they (things or people)?

Would the following answer be with (at), without it or either one?

> I left them (at) home

I have done a quick Google search and found quotes for both cases, with and without:

> This Widow's 4 Kids Were Taken After She **Left Them Home** Alone.
>
> **Leaving Your Child Home** Alone - KidsHealth
>
> Gerry said, "I **left them at home**." Gerry sat down and turned on the TV
> set just as Mark would have done.

I read about "home" being an adverb but also know "stay at home moms" for example. So you see I need definite answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the choice is between

*I left them at home*

and

*I left them home*

I would *always* choose **at home**.

*at home,* along with such other phrases as *at work* and *at school,* are fixed and extremely common. So common that I would not depart from them. I would also never say *I left them work* or *...school.*

Yes, *home* can be an adverb, but I would use this mainly to answer the question

*Where are you going?*

*(I'm going) home.*

As far as **home alone**, this expression is fine, in either

*He left the kids **at home alone.***

*He left the kids **home alone.***

But my feeling is that the use of the latter  phrase remains popular in some respects because of the popular movie of the same name: *[Home Alone](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0099785/)*, and its sequels.

Comment: The phrase was popular long before the movie existed.

Comment: @Octopus Exactly: ***remains** popular* is what I wrote.  And has now become an almost go-to phrase, in all sorts of contexts, because of the movie.

Answer (score 8):

**Both usages are acceptable.**

This is an easy one to get stuck on. The trick here is that *home* is both an *idea* and a *location*.

Consider the word *alone*.

You would say

> Leave me alone.

but not

> Leave me at alone.

because alone is an idea and not a location.

Conversely, *my house* is a location and not an idea.

So, you could say

> I forgot them at my house.

but not

> I forgot them my house.

Thus, when you say

> I left them home.

You are referring to the idea of home; whereas,

> I left them at home.

refers to the location.

Note that while these are slightly different usages of the word, they are commonly understood to mean the same thing.

---

### Edit:

To make things easier, *home* as a noun means

> the place where one lives

and as an adverb it means

> *at* the place where one lives

So, you can leave something *at* home (noun), or you can leave something home (adverb).

Comment: I disagree with this answer. The cases in the question only work because it is "home alone". "I left them home" does not ring grammatical with me.

Comment: @Octopus Personally, I think it's a matter of *what* is being left home. I would never say "I left my keys home", but I would say "I left my family home."

Comment: "I left my family home" is not a great example because family can be an adjective describing home as a noun similar to "childhood home". Home as an adverb is not "at home" the way I understand it; it is "to or toward home" as in "I went home". I don't know that I've ever heard a native speaker (AmE) say "I left it home". I've always heard it "I left it at home." It is however common to say something like "The school nurse sent her home."

Comment: It *should* be noted, though, as Octopus points out, that "home alone" is a collocation, so "left them home alone" does sound significantly less awkward than "left them home", even if it is technically grammatical to say that.

Comment: @neminem Yes I agree that "home alone" is a different case. My main objection is defining "home" as "at home" when it is an adverb. "The child was old enough to stay home alone." is fine.

Comment: @ColleenV those definitions are taken from Google.

Comment: Google isn't exactly an authoritative dictionary. Cambridge defines it as to or towards where you live. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/home?q=home+

Comment: @ColleenV Hmm... well, I've seen the use of *at* in a few different places. Additionally, what would you do with the sentence "stay home"? This seems like "stay *at* home" to me.

Comment: _"I decided to stay home."_ You wouldn't normally say "I decided to stay at calm." or "stay at here".  There is something special about home though because "stay at home" is OK and I'm having trouble coming up with another example of a location that works both as "stay home" and "stay at home". I think it is because home two definitions as a noun - the house you live in, and the place you feel you belong, i.e. "I lived up North for many years, but it never felt like home."

Answer (score 1):

They are both common but **at home** is more consistent with similar expressions such as **at work**.

I can't help but think of the German **heimgehen** and **nach Hause gehen** (= go home in both cases). The second formula is like in latin languages, where there is no such thing as home, there's just "the house", and you "go to the house" if you're going home (in French it would be "à la", in other languages it's often just "a/à" without the article), while the first makes sense only in German and English (go home/heimgehen). 
Marginal note: if you left something at home, it's **zu Hause**.

I'm a romance native speaker and I'm thus used to having particles such as **at** everywhere, while this is not so in germanic languages, except for English which is heavily influenced by French and so is a bit of a middle ground.

Considering all of this, I'm pretty sure that the popularity of **I left the kids home**  is definitely not due to a movie but it's due to some ancient germanic grammar, because the same "feature" is present in both German and English. 
Except that in German heim is always used without the equivalent of "at" so there's no ambiguity, you either say "home" without the "at" or you say "house".

All in all, I would be pretty sure that both are correct and it's not like either one of them is due to a modern fad.

Answer (score -2):

The examples without prepositions are *[headlinese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese)*. Writers often take liberty omitting the prepositions.

But then, to answer your question...

**Both are okay.** *Nevertheless,* I'd vote for *at home*.

The reason is *home* when serves as an *adverb* talks *more* about the *direction*. And this, as a special adverb, does not take any preposition. Compare:

> I am going/arriving/leaving *home* - **no preposition**

But then, once you *reach* home, you are *at home*.

Said that, if you want to specify the *location*, the preposition makes better sense.

> I left key/people ***at home***
>
> Will you be *at the office* tonight at 9 pm? ~ *No. I will be **at home** that time. Call me on my residence number.*

However, in ***AmE***, [*at* is still omitted in this case.](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv240.shtml)

Comment: (AmE perspective): No one I know says *at office*, but *at work*. Also, as an AmE speaker I'd say *I'll be at home at that time* and would rarely omit the first *at*, never the second.

Comment: "at the office" is fine though.