# What part of speech is "home"?

Tags: articles, parts-of-speech

What part of speech is "home" in the sentence:

> I enjoyed being at home

My teacher says: "That is an adverb".  It looks like a nonsense but just in case.

The question was raised due to the determination whether we use an article or not.

Comment: [related on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385396/can-home-be-an-adjective-as-well-as-an-adverb-or-a-noun)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I left them (at) home](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40277/i-left-them-at-home)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78757/discussion-on-question-by-dirty-hippy-what-part-of-speech-is-home).

Answer (score 1):

Weird, I was considering that exact question yesterday, apropos of (so far as I can remember) nothing at all.

In the sentence

> I enjoyed being home

"Home" is arguably an adjective.  Compare it to "I enjoyed being rich" or "I enjoyed being beautiful".

In the sentence

> I enjoyed being *at* home

"Home" is a noun, it's the object of a preposition. Compare it to "I enjoyed being in Cleveland" or "I enjoyed being under water".

Answer (score 1):

In the sentence

> I enjoyed being at home

"at" is a preposition, and "home" is the object of the preposition.

Answer (score 0):

Your teacher is right. 
Consider the syntax structure of the sentence:
I enjoyed being at home - **subject** (*I*) **verb** (*enjoyed*) **verb complement** (*being*) **adverb of place** (*at home*)

**AT HOME** is a phrase and **no article** is used.