# Is this sentence with 'home' after 'should be' grammatical?

Tags: grammar, syntax, parts-of-speech

> Gerry should be home in an hour.

('Home' after 'should be' is making me confused.)

Comment: Take a look at https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40277/i-left-them-at-home, which looks at various cases of "home" being used without a prepostion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you specify a location where someone *is*, or other forms of *to be*, it always follows the verb, and goes before any temporal information ('in an hour' in your case).

Situations where it does not *directly* follow the verb are exceptions:

- In questions: "Are you home now?"
- Certain adverbs: "I am almost there."

Comment: *It* in your answer  refers to "be" as in the infinite (be) comes after the modal verb (should) or does it refer to the adverb "home"?  The OP, I believe, is talking about this usage: *He **should be at** work* vs *He **should be** home*, *They* ***walked home*** vs *They* **should walk to** *the store*

Comment: @Mari-LouA As I am sure you are aware, in Britain we would only say "He should be home" if it meant he had reached home. If we were indicating a person's whereabouts, unlike Americans, who would say "He should be home", we would say "He should be at home".